# Where has my GarageBand gone?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, garageband

I own a 2011 MBP, which came with GarageBand installed. I am not complaining, but suddenly I don't get updates for it anymore. The AppStore lists GarageBand as having an update, but when I click the update button it tells me that there are no updates for this Apple ID.

Looking at the AppStore page for GarageBand, I can see it available for 4,99 EUR. I don't really mind, since I got it for free and don't use it really, but I am still wondering how this could happen? Did Apple change the terms on when I am eligible for updates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small print at the bottom of the download info page for the GarageBand ver 10.1.

**- Requires Apple Music Connect Account**

Do you have one ?

But here is the good news. I do not have the Apple Music Connect and was able to get the GarageBand 10.1 update.

I have a MBA 2012 with Mavericks (10.9.5) and here is the process I had to do.

[image: need to accept this]

need to accept this then continue with download

[image: paused]

[image: download]

[image: installing]

[image: done]

You will be asked to log in again to complete the download/installation.

And it is ready to go:

[image: gb ready]

Comment: This indeed worked. At some point I got asked to agree to the terms and conditions, and now after a good night's sleep it allows me to upgrade.